# Can't work with MS SQL database in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am trying to connect to MS SQL database in Doctrine 2.0, but I get this error all the time: *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'*.

I have already found that I need to install PDO SqlSrv extension to my local PHP (using Wamp), so I have done it (copied dlls into ext folder, edited php.ini, restarted), but the problem is still the same. I am trying to use some drivers I have downloaded, name of the file is `SQLSRV20.EXE`. In Doctrine config I have this as a driver: `pdo_sqlsrv`.

Has anybody same experience or is here just somebody who knows what have I to do to make it work?

Comment: Look into the `phpinfo()` it lists the PDO driver actually installed. Is it in that list?

Comment: Right, thats another thing I could do before. Now I see it is not there, but I dont understand why :/  PDO drivers  mysql, odbc, sqlite

Comment: Okay infact this is not bad news. It just means not installed. What have you edited in the php.ini? And where did you obtain the .dll file from?

Comment: This is what I added to php.ini:

extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll

The php_pdo.dll is downloaded from dlldll.com, the sqlsrv DLLs are downloaded from microsoft.com. Originals names were a little bit different, I have renamed it in my trying to make it work.

Comment: Restore the original filenames. Obtain php_pdo.dll from php.net, it should be part of you PHP. Where did you obtain PHP from? Which version do you use?

Comment: PHP version 5.3.4, downloaded it as part of WAMP server.

Comment: So, I have made a little progress. I found another php.ini (dunno why, but htere are 2) and updated this second one. Now I have this problem: when I start server, it writes error looking somehow like this (tha last sentence is in my language, so its translated here): PHP Startup: Unable to laod dynamic library 'C:/ ... /ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll' - %1 is not valid application of Win32 type.

Comment: Okay, this clearly signals that the .dll you downloaded is incompatible with your php version. That's not only the version number (e.g. 5.2 / 5.3) but also TS or Non-TS (TS=Thread-Safe, Non-TS= Not Thread Safe). Additionally it needs to be the same bit version (32bit or 64bit).

Comment: Guess there will be problem in bit version, I got x64

Comment: If you're running PHP in 32 bit, use the 32bit dll from the microsoft homepage.

Comment: My PHP is 64 bit TS (as phpinfo() says) and these DLLs I downloaded from MS don't work (still same error). Guess these are all 32 bit and I need 64 bit?

Comment: If your PHP is 64bit, then you need to use 64bit DLL's I'm pretty sure, yes.

Comment: OK, problem seems to be solved, I just installed 32-bit PHP and SQLSRV extension installed succesfully. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  My PHP is 64bit TS also (Windows 7).  I have :

Comment: Install 32-bit version (it works on 64-bit system too). Than the extension should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a heck of a job trying to get PDO driver's working - it turned out i just needed to reboot my system.

..this shouldn't have been necessary but it did work. So if you are sure you have taken all the steps necessary to enable the drivers and it's still not working, give the reboot a shot.